# I have a kotlin String variable and I want to execute the string as Kotlin code

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am using jetpack Compose to make an android application and I want to create a function that takes a string as one of its parameters and execute it at a specific order

for example in python we had exec which enables you to execute the string for example if I run this python code

```
def Home (String):
    print("____________Some execution to do____________________")

    exec(String)
    
    print("____________Some execution to do____________________")

mycode ="""i=0
while True:
    if i==10:
        break
    print("Executing")
    i+=1
    """

Home(mycode)
```

I will get this result

```
____________Some execution to do____________________
Executing
Executing
Executing
Executing
Executing
Executing
Executing
Executing
Executing
Executing
____________Some execution to do____________________
```

is there an similar way to do the same thing in Kotlin ?

I used

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.5'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.3.5'
```

in the dependencies and imported

```
import kotlinx.serialization.builtins.serializer
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
```

but I get an error of Unresolved reference: serialization

Comment: Kotlin is not a scripting language, but a compiled language, so this is not that trivial or even impossible to do. We would need a Kotlin compiler running inside the Android application.

Comment: Look for a different approach.  In a safe, statically-typed language like Kotlin, executing arbitrary code would be a huge security hole; it would also be slow, fragile, and hard to debug.  That's why it's not provided as a standard function.  As broot says, there may be a way by bundling and calling the compiler, and then loading and running the results, but if so it would be a lot of hard work.  There's very likely a better approach, if you can find it.